# перегрузка оператора * для структуры

Tags: c++, указатели, структуры, перегрузка-операторов

Требуется, чтобы унарный оператор * возвращал значение поля data. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём состоит моя ошибка.

```
/*...*/

struct Node{
    int data;
    Node *prev, *next;

    Node(int const& data, Node* next = nullptr, Node* prev = nullptr)
    : data(data)
    , next(next)
    , prev(prev) {}

    Node(int&& data, Node* next = nullptr, Node* prev = nullptr)
    : data(std::move(data))
    , next(next)
    , prev(prev) {}

    /*...*/

    int operator *(Node* p) {
        return p->data;
    }
};

int main() {
    Node* c = new Node(5);
    std::cout << *c; // fail
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас аргумент оператора лишний.
Функции_члены класса первым аргументом неявно получают указатель(`this`) на данный  объект, поэтому оператор нужно определить так:

```
int operator *() {
    return data;
}
```

Для каждого объекта оператор вернет свое целочисленное значение, и можно написать так:

```
Node obj(5);
std::cout << *obj;
```

А указатель нужно разыменовывать:

```
Node* c = new Node(5);
std::cout << **c; // или же
std::cout << c->operator*();
```